# How to exceed parent div when child dropdown opens

Tags: html, css, layout, drop-down-menu, html-select

Now I can see the `select` like this one below. As you can see the dropdown options are bigger than my parent `div`. Height of parent `div` called container doesn't change when I open the dropdown menu.

[image]

This is my HTML & CSS code

```
<div class="container">
     <select name="users" id="users">
         <option value="cindy">Cindy</option>
         <option value="tom">Tom</option>
         <option value="paul">Paul</option>
         <option value="miley">Miley</option>
      </select>
</div>

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 200px;
}
```

I would like to exceed parent `div` (its height actually), when the dropdown item is open as below.

[image]

Do you know how to do that? I tried to use `display: table`, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items are going to be in the `select` you can extend its parent `div` by adding bottom margin to the `select` when it is focused. Example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 200px;
}

select:focus {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <select name="users" id="users">
         <option value="cindy">Cindy</option>
         <option value="tom">Tom</option>
         <option value="paul">Paul</option>
         <option value="miley">Miley</option>
      </select>
</div>
```